# How I can open a file in Google Drive ? - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-drive-api

I'm working on a special Cordova Application. And I want to know, how I can open a file with my Cordova application ?

The Fact is I have a file in my Google Drive. And I want when a user go to Google Drive Application and try to do "Open file with", google drive purpose to open the file with my Cordova application.

Comment: Google is your friend. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js

Comment: The fact is i don't think that i need Google Drive Api but a special package for cordova to tell that he need to open file

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i found the solution x) : http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event